# OpenCV3 installation on Mac

Tags: macos, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I tried to install OpenCV3 for Mac with the following command in terminal:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib -with-ffmpeg
```

It repeatedly gets stuck at this point:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Xcode command line tools first. Go to the AppStore and download and install Xcode from Apple for free.

Then run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

to get `make`,`cmake`, and all the command-line development tools.

---

Also, consider adding the QuickTime back-end, by additionally specifying `--with-qt5`, i.e.:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib -with-ffmpeg --with-qt5
```

That gives you extra options to save the images you generate and display with the `highgui` module.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the exact same issue. Someone else had also reported this [problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5128) on the brew github, but they could also not reproduce the issue. In my case though, it would go a step further and get stuck after calling `make` for **hours**:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE
make
```

I went ahead and tracked the processes in the Activity Monitor on my Mac and found out that it kicks off a batch of clang processes in sequence on multiple threads. But I had several apps running that were robbing it of CPU and Memory resources. So I shut down Safari, Finder, IDEs (XCode, PyCharm) etc, and this time it did complete.

**Solution**: was to just let it run with as much CPU and memory overhead it needs. And with no other power-hungry apps running in the background, it finished in 25mins.

**CMake Approach:**
Your next best approach is to bypass using package manager, like brew, and follow the instructions given on [PyImageSearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/) to build OpenCV manually using CMake:

1. Install dependencies like CMake, pkg-config (and possibly others...)
2. Clone OpenCV and OpenCV_Contrib git repos:

   1. https://github.com/opencv/opencv
   2. https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
3. Checkout version [e.g. 3.2.0]
4. Make `build` directory inside `opencv` directory
5. Run CMake with the appropriate parameters for your system:

   `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv3 \
   -D PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages \
   -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=/usr/local/opt/python/bin \
   -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
   -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=ON \
   -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
   -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
   -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/Salman_Naqvi/Downloads/opencv_contrib/modules ..`
6. Compile using: `make -j4`
7. Install it on MacOS: `make install`

--> It'll be installed in the directory specified by: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv3`